# .append not working with spaces

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add and remove `<li>`'s to a `<ul>` using the data from within the class `add-to-favourites`, the problem is that when I have more than one word or a space between words the jQuery no longer recognises that it is the same word and adds the same value to the `<ul>` again.

You can see the problem here: **http://jsfiddle.net/ZWxBb/**

Try clicking on the rows of text you will see they are added and removed to the `<ul>` except for the first instance of class which is just added everytime it is clicked.

It would also be great if you could use more than 2 words as the element text, plus add a div which when clicked removed the item from favourites

HTML:

```
<div class="add-to-favourites">Two Words</div>
<div class="add-to-favourites">OneWords</div>
<div class="add-to-favourites">NoSpaces</div>
<ul id="favourites"></ul>
```

​
jQuery:

```
$(function () {
$('.add-to-favourites').click(function() {
   var num = $(this).text();
   var $fav = $('#favourites');
   var $fav_li = $fav.find('.' + num + '_li');

   if ($fav_li.length) {
      $fav_li.remove();
   } else {
      $('#favourites').append('<li class="' + num + '_li">' + num + '</li>');
   }
})
});
```

​
Thanks,
Ben

Comment: class names can't have spaces, you will have to convert the spaces into &nbsp; or something else to identify them

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/449000/106866) for valid CSS class names

Comment: Can you please move your code to the question? The question loses lots of value if JSFiddle is down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As lzzey said, class names cannot contain spaces. Try doing a .replace(" ", "_" ) on your class matching:

```
$('.add-to-favourites').click(function() {
   var num = $(this).text();
   var numClass = num.replace(" ", "_" );
   var $fav = $('#favourites');
   var $fav_li = $fav.find('.' + numClass  + '_li');

   if ($fav_li.length) {
      $fav_li.remove();
   } else {
      $('#favourites').append('<li class="' + numClass  + '_li">' + num + '</li>');
   }
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZWxBb/2/

**UPDATE:**

I would suggest using something other that the text to identify the li's

Html:

```
<div class="add-to-favourites" data-item="1">Two Words</div>
<div class="add-to-favourites" data-item="2">One asd asd asd asd Words</div>
<div class="add-to-favourites" data-item="3">NoSpaces</div>
```

Then js:

```
$('.add-to-favourites').click(function() {
   var num = $(this).data( "item" );
   var text = $(this).text();
   var $fav = $('#favourites');
   var $fav_li = $fav.find('.' + num + '_li');

   if ($fav_li.length) {
      $fav_li.remove();
   } else {
      $('#favourites').append('<li class="' + num + '_li">' + text + '</li>');
   }
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZWxBb/3/

Comment: Thank you, but is it possible for it to work no matter how many words, for example the original problem persists if you use two or more words

Comment: I would use something other than the text() to indetify the li's: http://jsfiddle.net/ZWxBb/3/

Comment: Thanks for your help Matt, this is excellent. How would I add a new class to the added `<li>` element which when clicked removed it from the list?

Comment: No problem! You mean, clicking on a li in favourites removes it as well? Easy: http://jsfiddle.net/vUyDk/


Please note the .live function to bind the click, it works a bit differently than .click (http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: thank you, but rather than clicking on the li itself which was added to favourites I would rather click on a new span in the li which was added to favourites which contained the word 'remove'. Is this possible? when I opened your jsfiddle I couldn't get that functionality to work

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `class` attribute of an HTML element to define multiple classes by separating them with a space. When your element text contains one or more spaces, two things happen:

This line will never select any elements, because you end up with the wrong selector.

```
var $fav_li = $fav.find('.' + num + '_li');
```

And this line:

```
$('#favourites').append('<li class="' + num + '_li">' + num + '</li>');
```

will append an element with at least two classes on it.

My suggestion is to replace spaces with dashes after storing the text in `num`, and use that for selecting by or assigning your single class:

```
var num = $(this).text().replace(' ', '-');
```

[**Updated DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZWxBb/1/)

Comment: Thank you, but is there a way for it to work when the element text contains more than 2 words. If you look at your demo and try to use 3 words the original problem is back.

Answer (score 1):

Class names cannot contain spaces because in CSS selectors, spaces are used to separate each selector. So when you click on the `Two Words` div, you end up trying to select `.Two Words_li`, which is elements with the class name `Two` and child elements with the tag name `Words_li`.

One way to deal with this would be to convert all the spaces to a different character.

```
var num = $(this).text().replace( /\s+/g, "-" );
```

Comment: Thank you, it looks like this doesn't work for more than 2 words though? for example, with 3 words the original problem is back.

Comment: Just add a `g` to the regexp: `/\s+/g`.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you add the 'num' var as a CSS class name. CSS class names cannot have spaces. You should replace spaces and specials characters with an empty string before using them as a CSS class name.